# How to calculate number of business days in Golang

Tags: go

I have this so far to count the number of days using http://golang.org/pkg/time/ but I don't know how to exclude weekends and only count business days.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    f := time.Date(2015, time.August, 21, 24, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    diff := f.Sub(t)

    // convert diff to days
    days := int(diff.Hours() / 24)

    fmt.Printf("days  %d\n", days)
}
```

Comment: You could get the day of week (using  Weekday) for the "t" and "f". Knowing how many days are between t and f you can calculate how many weekends there are.

Comment: That gives me a number like Friday = 5 and thursday =4 so if I did an if statement like if t.Weekday() ==6 and decrement that that should reduce the number of days by every Saturday but how do I loop through the days?

Comment: Can't you create an algorithm, for every 7 days there are 5 business data. For the remaining days if day of week of start is layer then end there is a weekend in between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple little solution.

```
days := 0
for {
     if (t.Equal(f)) {
         return days
     }
     if (t.Weekday() != time.Saturday && t.Weekday() != time.Sunday) {
          days++
     }
     t = t.Add(time.Hour*24)
}
```

You probably don't want to use your original `t` variable but keeping the example simple. I loop until `t` equals `f`, if they're equal I return my days count. If they're not I check to make sure it's a weekday and increment my days count if it is. I unconditionally add one day to my starting time.

Comment: Hm... this is okay but I believe there is a better way using modulo.

Comment: @FUZxxl I was planning to do modulo but I don't think actually makes any difference. You still have to iterate over time and you can't like "range" a `Duration` as far as I can tell. If I just chose to use modulo within my current code it would make no difference. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can divide the number of days by seven to get the number of weeks and than multiply by five to get the number of week-days. Then you need to do some sort of fixup so the number is correct. This is an O(1) procedure as opposed to your O(n) procedure and should be a lot faster, especially for longer periods. I'm too tired right now to work through the details though.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted a solution which doesn't need a loop to calculate the number of days. (The posted answers by `md2perpe`, `vinceg` and `Scott Owens` however didn't work for me and calculated wrong results.)

Here is solution which doesn't require a loop:

(The solution calculates full weeks and loose days separately and adds them later.)

```golang
func calculateWorkingDays(startTime time.Time, endTime time.Time) int {
    // Reduce dates to previous Mondays
    startOffset := weekday(startTime)
    startTime = startTime.AddDate(0, 0, -startOffset)
    endOffset := weekday(endTime)
    endTime = endTime.AddDate(0, 0, -endOffset)

    // Calculate weeks and days
    dif := endTime.Sub(startTime)
    weeks := int(math.Round((dif.Hours() / 24) / 7))
    days := -min(startOffset, 5) + min(endOffset, 5)

    // Calculate total days
    return weeks*5 + days
}

func weekday(d time.Time) int {
    wd := d.Weekday()
    if wd == time.Sunday {
        return 6
    }
    return int(wd) - 1
}

func min(a int, b int) int {
    if a < b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

First, the weekday offset of the start and end date are calculated and both dates are reduced to the previous Monday. Then, the number of full weeks and loose days are calculated. (If a offset it larger than 5(Friday), only 5 days are used.) Finally, the total days are calculated.

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been marked done for a while, but for various reasons I recently had to get the number of weekdays between two dates that could be decades apart.

So if anyone needs it, an O(1) solution.

```
func GetWeekdaysBetween(start, end time.Time) int {
    offset := -int(start.Weekday())
    start = start.AddDate(0, 0, -int(start.Weekday()))

    offset += int(end.Weekday())
    if end.Weekday() == time.Sunday {
        offset++
    }
    end = end.AddDate(0, 0, -int(end.Weekday()))

    dif := end.Sub(start).Truncate(time.Hour * 24)
    weeks := float64((dif.Hours() / 24) / 7)
    return int(math.Round(weeks)*5) + offset
}
```

If your wanting business days though, this doesn't account for public holidays, which would require some additional planning.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. Thank you `evanmcdonnal` and `luc` for answering.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t := time.Date(2015, time.Now().Month(), time.Now().Day(), time.Now().Hour(), time.Now().Minute(), time.Now().Second(), time.Now().Nanosecond()*0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",t)
    f := time.Date(2015, time.August, 22, time.Now().Hour(), time.Now().Minute(), time.Now().Second(), time.Now().Nanosecond()*0, time.UTC)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",f)

    days := 0
    for {
        if (t.Equal(f)) {
            break
        }
        if (t.Weekday() != 6 && t.Weekday() != 0) {
            days++
        }
        t = t.Add(time.Hour*24)
    }

    fmt.Printf("days %d\n", days)
}
```

Output: 32

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `AddDate` for time calculations greater than 24 hours:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func AddWorkDays(t time.Time, workdays int) time.Time {
    curDate := t
    for curWorkdays := 0; curWorkdays <= workdays; {
        curDate = curDate.AddDate(0, 0, 1)
        if curDate.Weekday() != 6 && t.Weekday() != 7 {
            curWorkdays++
        }
    }
    return curDate
}

func main() {
    now := time.Now()
    workdays := 3
    t := AddWorkDays(now, workdays)
    fmt.Printf("  now %-9v %v\n", now.Weekday(), now)
    fmt.Printf("later %-9v %v\n", t.Weekday(), t)
}
```

Output on day I'm answering:

```
  now Friday    2017-03-10 21:33:28.395198671 +0000 UTC
later Wednesday 2017-03-15 21:33:28.395198671 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

Realizing that we are calculating an integral and remembering that integrals are usually calculated using primitive functions, which can be taken to be the integral from some fixed time, we can write the following code.

The function `primitive()` gives the number of workdays since 3 January 2000, chosen to be a Monday to simplify the formula. The number of workdays between two dates is then given by the difference of `primitive()` for the two days.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Date struct {
    year int
    month time.Month
    day int
}

func date2unix(d Date, loc *time.Location) int64 {
    return time.Date(d.year, d.month, d.day, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc).Unix()
}

func primitive(d Date, loc *time.Location) int64 {
    // 3 January 2000 was a Monday
    base := Date{2000, time.January, 3}
    seconds := date2unix(d, loc) - date2unix(base, loc)
    weeks := seconds / (7*24*60*60)
    seconds_into_week := seconds % (7*24*60*60)
    workdays := seconds_into_week / (24*60*60)
    if workdays > 5 {
        workdays = 5
    }

    return 5*weeks + workdays
}

func DayCountExcludingWeekends(from, to Date, loc *time.Location) int {
    return int(primitive(to, loc) - primitive(from, loc))
}

func main() {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Stockholm")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    f := Date{2017, 6, 28}
    t := Date{2017, 7,  6}

    fmt.Println(DayCountExcludingWeekends(f, t, loc))
}
```

- https://play.golang.org/p/_wxw8-PyMO
- https://goplay.space/#wWU0Stv5zO

Answer (score 0):

CalcBusinessDays calculates the business days between two dates, not accounting for the holidays.
The calculation is inclusive for both dates.

```
func CalcBusinessDays(from *time.Time, to *time.Time) int {

totalDays := float32(to.Sub(*from) / (24 * time.Hour))
weekDays := float32(from.Weekday()) - float32(to.Weekday())
businessDays := int(1 + (totalDays*5-weekDays*2)/7)
if to.Weekday() == time.Saturday {
    businessDays--
}
if from.Weekday() == time.Sunday {
    businessDays--
}

return businessDays
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old question but might want to consider a solution that does not use a loop:

https://gist.github.com/khirvy019/5c5eea7564c953cabf49da0fb0c35dc8

```
import (
    "time"
)

func AddBusinessDays(date time.Time, noOfDays int) time.Time {
    actualDateAfterNoOfDays := date.Add(time.Duration(noOfDays) * 24 * time.Hour)
    noOfWorkingDaysInBetween := GetWorkingDaysInBetween(date, actualDateAfterNoOfDays)

    additionalDaysNeeded := noOfDays - noOfWorkingDaysInBetween

    fmt.Println(date, ",", actualDateAfterNoOfDays, ",", noOfWorkingDaysInBetween)
    if additionalDaysNeeded <= 0 {
        return actualDateAfterNoOfDays
    }

    return actualDateAfterNoOfDays.Add(
        AddBusinessDays(actualDateAfterNoOfDays, additionalDaysNeeded).Sub(actualDateAfterNoOfDays),
    )
}

// GetWorkingDaysInBetween ...
func GetWorkingDaysInBetween(s, e time.Time) int {
    sW := int(s.Weekday())
    n := GetDaysInBetween(s, e)
    saturdays := DayOfWeekCount(sW, 6, n)
    sundays := DayOfWeekCount(sW, 0, n)

    // formula excludes end date thus must add one if the date is a weekday
    additional := 1
    if e.Weekday() == time.Saturday || e.Weekday() == time.Sunday {
        additional = 0
    }
    return n - (saturdays + sundays) + additional
}

func GetDaysInBetween(s, e time.Time) int {
    return int(e.Sub(s).Hours() / 24.0)
}

func DayOfWeekCount(startDayOfWeek, targetDayOfWeek, noOfDays int) int {
    // Gives number of a weekday given; a starting weekday and number of days
    // startDayOfWeek, targetDayOfWeek are indexed 0 ([0..6] => [Sunday ... Saturday])
    x := CircularSequenceDistance(startDayOfWeek, targetDayOfWeek, 7)
    y := int(float64(noOfDays) / 7)
    z := 0
    z1 := CircularSequenceDistance(startDayOfWeek, ((startDayOfWeek+noOfDays) % 7)-1, 7)
    if z1 >= x {
        z = 1
    }

    return y + z
}

// CircularSequenceDistance
func CircularSequenceDistance(from, to, length int) int {
    return ((to - from) + length) % length
}
```